# Find and Replace specific column, but only when it equals a specific value

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

How do I replace column 132 (either a space or a Y) with a character (N), but only when column 132 = a space?

Looking at other threads here I've come up with a way to replace column 132 with an N:

-Find: ^(.{132})(.)

-Replace: \1N

...but that will replace column 132 in *every* row and doesn't account for the space. Thanks for your help!

**Full scenario:**
I have a character-length defined document where each line has either a space or a Y in the 132 column. In any line where there is a space there I need to replace it with an N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.{131}\K`   <--- there is a space after the K
- Replace with: `N`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : beginning of line
.{131}  : 131 any character
\K      : forget all we have seen until this position
a space
```